# bash functions, local variables, and exit codes

Tags: bash, variables, exit-code

In a bash function, I'm trying to capture the output of a command along with it's exit code.  Generally, my form is

```
some_function() {
local rv=$(some_other_function)
local code=$?
echo "$rv"
return $code
}
```

but I notice that whenever I use 'local', then $? is ALWAYS 0.  Like it's capturing the result of the assignment, not the called function.
If I don't use 'local', then it works as expected:

```
$ foo() { local rv=$(false); echo "code is $?"; }
$ foo
code is 0
$ foo() { rv=$(false); echo "code is $?"; }
$ foo
code is 1
```

Can someone explain this to me?  Obviously something fundamental here I just don't understand.

Comment: There's another problem with `local rv=$(some_other_function)` -- in some shells (not including bash), the output from `some_other_function` will be word-split before being passed to `local`; the first word will be assigned to `rv`, and the rest will be treated as separate identifiers to be marked as local variables (except for the ones that aren't valid identifiers). It's safest to just always double-quote command substitutions, e.g. `local rv="$(some_other_function)"`, just like you should variable references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can someone explain this to me?

In simple words most of the time `$?` has the exit status of last command executed. The **last** command is `local`. The return status of `local` is zero - it successfully made `rv` a local variable. Stupid example:

```
echo $(false) $(true) $(false)
^^^^ - this is the last command executed
# $? here has exit status of **echo**
```

Separate the assignment from `local`:

```
local rv code
# Assignment is not a "command", in the sense it preserves exit status.
# The last command executed in assignment is the one inside `$(...)`.
rv=$(some_other_function)
code=$?  # will have the exit status of expression executed inside $(...)
```

Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net . Shellcheck warns about such mistakes.

Comment: Specifically, this is the wiki entry for this issue: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155